# Performance Improvements in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, lazy-evaluation

I want to improve my haskell skills of writing really performant code (coming from a C/C++ Background this is important for my ego :D).

So I have written two functions to calculate Pi by the Leibnitz Formula (its not about calculation pi, it was just an example):

```
calcPiStep k = (if even k then 4.0 else -4.0) / (2.0*fromIntegral k + 1.0)
calcPiN n = foldl (\p x -> p + calcPiStep x) 0.0 [0..n]
calcPiInf = toinf [0..] 0
    where
        toinf = \(x:xs) l -> do 
            let curr = l + calcPiStep x
            curr:toinf xs curr
```

calcPiInf constructs a infinite List by recursion. calcPiN with a foldl and a lambda with n iterations.

I have found that calcPiInf is faster than calcPiN AND does not run into a stack overflow for too large numbers.
**First question:** is this just because of lazy evaluation?

Secondly I wrote a corresponding C++ Program:

```
using namespace std;
double calcPi(int n){
    double pi = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++){
        pi += 4.0*(i%2 == 0?1:-1)/(2.0*i + 1.0);
    }
    return pi;
}
int main(){
    std::cout.precision(10);
    cout << calcPi(5000000) << endl;
}
```

Which is *far* faster than my Haskell Solution. Is it theoretically possible to rewrite my Haskell Code to achieve a similar performance as in C++?

Comment: If you're interested in a review, then [CodeReview.SE] might be more suitable for your question.

Comment: Benchmarking is hard. How did you actually time these? It's not at all obvious, because your two definitions don't even do the same thing: one of them is a list, and the other is a function from number to number. At least it is easy to say that laziness is one possible issue: `foldl` is never a good idea, and `foldl'` would be an improvement.

Comment: Hardware platform, compilers, compiler versions, optimization levels ? Also did you try with foldl' and foldr ?

Comment: General suggestions: 1) Provide specific type annotations e.g. `::Double`, 2) never use `foldl`, use `foldl'` for computing numeric values, 3) avoid GHCi, compile with ghc and `-O2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use `foldl'` (from `Data.List`) instead of `foldl` (and prefer that variant compared to a lazily generated list)
2. Use explicit type signatures, or you end up with `Integer`.
3. Use optimizations (`-O2`)

The following code takes ~3.599s on my system (GHC 8.0.2, no optimizations)

```
calcPiStep k = (if even k then 4.0 else -4.0) / (2.0*fromIntegral k + 1.0)
calcPiN n = foldl (\p x -> p + calcPiStep x) 0.0 [0..n]

main = print $ calcPiN 5000000
```

Using `foldl'` instead of `foldl` yields ~1.7s (only ~40% of the original time).

```
import Data.List
calcPiStep k = (if even k then 4.0 else -4.0) / (2.0*fromIntegral k + 1.0)
calcPiN n = foldl' (\p x -> p + calcPiStep x) 0.0 [0..n]

main = print $ calcPiN 5000000
```

Using type signatures yields ~0.8s, or another 50% reduction. If we now add optimizations, we end up with `0.066s`, which is still around twice as slow as the C++ variant (0.033s on my machine with `-O3`, gcc), but it's almost there.

Note that we could also have used `-O2` immediately to get below a single second, but any improvement *before* adding `-O2` often (but not necessarily!) also leads to an improvement afterwards.

Here are all times depending on whether type signatures, `foldl'` or optimization flags were used. Note that type signatures together with `-O2` already bring us to close to C++'s speed. However, that behaviour might not hold in general, and we need to change some functions depending on the lazyness:

| Type annotations | `foldl'` | `-O2` | Runtime [s] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | no | yes | 0.063 |
| yes | yes | yes | 0.063 |
| no | yes | yes | 0.180 |
| no | no | yes | 0.190 |
| yes | yes | no | 0.825 |
| no | yes | no | 1.700 |
| yes | no | no | 2.477 |
| no | no | no | 3.599 |

Comment: Increasing the 5000000 figure here seems to make the gap more evident. GHC is running at 6x times on my machine using 500000000. I did not expect that.

Comment: @chi 6x times compared to the C++ variant? I still get around factor 2 between GHC's optimized code and g++ `-O3`, even with 500000000.

Comment: Yes, 3.633s GHC, 0.550s g++, so it's ~7x slower. I'll try again later, maybe I got something wrong.

Comment: @chi Huh. Cannot reproduce *that* gap. I get ~2.272s (g++ -O3) vs ~4.972s (GHC -O2), so ~2.4x slower. However, my GCC and GHC aren't the most recent ones. I'll have a look into the profile.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot, especially to know about Integer and foldl' :)

Comment: @Zeta My oldish g++ -O3 7.5.0 seems to be much faster than yours. My GHC -O2 8.6.5 is more in line with your numbers. Neither of us is really using the latest compilers.

Comment: On my machine, using `-fllvm` speeds this up even more, about 6x as fast with `-fllvm` as without. (As a rule of thumb, heavy numeric computations often benefit from `-fllvm`.)